# Selecting a random record from Sequelize findAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently brute-forcing this, but am confident there is a better solution that uses Sequelize, the code in question (using postgres):

```
...
then((tile_data) => {
  return Encounter.findAll({
    where: {
      level: tile_data.dataValues.level
    },
    transaction: transaction_data
  }).then((encounter_data) => {
    let encounter = encounter_data[Math.floor((Math.random() * encounter_data.length))].dataValues
    return Battle.create({
      character_id: character_data.dataValues.id,
      encounter_id: encounter.id,
      encounter_hp: encounter.max_hp,
      encounter_mana: encounter.max_mana
    }, {
      transaction: transaction_data
    })
...
```

Aside from seeming 'ugly', with this code I am loading all ENCOUNTERS into memory just to pluck one element out of the array.

Does anyone know how to do this through Sequelize, ideally without using a raw query?

Thank you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can try this :

```
Encounter.findAll({ order: Sequelize.literal('rand()'), limit: 5 }).then((encounters) => {
        // single random encounter
    });
```

Don't forget to require the Sequelize

Comment: This solution worked best for my MySQL project. Thank you!

Comment: This worked. I tried with SQL Server and used the function "NEWID()" instead "rand()"

Comment: Note that the function name literal would be 'random()' for postgres.

Answer (score 23):

I think this solution is the most clear one. You should use a random function from a sequelize instance

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(url, opts);
```

Recommend to use a sequelize-cli to generate initial schema, it automatically exports sequelize variable.

```
Encounter.findOne({ 
  order: sequelize.random() 
});
```

Also with this approach u don't need to solve `RAND()` vs `RANDOM()` problem if you change a db dialect from postgres to MySQL or back.

Answer (score 11):

```
Encounter.findOne({ order: 'random()' }).then((encounter) => {
    // single random encounter
});
```

`random()` should be used in case of PostgreSQL, in case of MySQL you would probably use `rand()`. You did not specify what database are you using.

**Edit**

Or if you really want to use `.findAll()`:

```
Encounter.findAll({ order: 'random()', limit: 1 }).then((encounter) => {
    // single random encounter
});
```

Comment: you cant use a string in a order this way, you missing literal

Comment: The current version of sequalize doesn't support order as string, 
you need to use
`order:[Sequelize.literal('RAND()')]`
don't forget to add 
`var Sequelize = require('sequelize');`

Answer (score 5):

Recommended way, for all db dialects, as of today, **5/2/19**

```
order: sequelize.random()
```

Comment: It should be mentions its in sequelize intance, not in sequelize module

Answer (score 3):

this code is presented as an example tested with mysql and sequelize@4.22.5 for those in need

```
   Encounter.findAll({
      order: [
        [Sequelize.literal('RAND()')]
      ],

      limit: 1,

    }).then((resp) => {
      callback(null, resp)
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

We can easily use findOne + order rand like this:

```
...
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
...

MyModel.findOne({
  order: [
    Sequelize.fn( 'RAND' ),
  ]
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3156#issuecomment-74792600

Answer (score 2):

As of today that is October 2020.

In Sequelize mysql below code works:

```
exports.uniqueRegistercodes = async (req) => {
    // console.log("code");
    const code = await registercodesModal.findAll({ order: db.sequelize.random(), limit: 1 });
    console.log("DATA CODE...");
    return code;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you split the operation into two steps?

1. Count the number of rows in the table `Encounter.count({ where: ... })`
2. Take that number can compute the encounter value. Then if you use integers for primary keys you can do a `Encounter.findById(encounterId)`

Even with this taking will be much more network efficient if the number of records in your DB gets large.

Answer (score 1):

In Sequelize version 6. We can use `sequelize.random()` to selecting random records from database, like this below

```
let products = await Product.findAll({
  order: sequelize.random()
})
```

ref: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#examples-with--code-op-not--code-

Answer (score 1):

Check this code in Sequelize mysql:

```
exports.uniqueRegistercodes = async (req) => {
    const code = await registercodesModal.findAll({ 
         order: db.sequelize.random(), limit: 1 });
    return code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Postgres findAll and findAndCountAll.

```
order: Sequelize.literal('random()')
```

Comment: Find One also works: `.findOne({ order: Sequelize.literal("random()") })`